# Can I pass multiple Id's inside a document.getelementbyID?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which has got 45 dropdownlist and I m using the bottom code for its 
validation.

how can I use only one function of bottom code to do validation for all of my 45 dropdownlist ??

**Here is the Function**

```
function Validate()
{
var e = document.getElementById("dropdownlistone");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
var strUser1 = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
if(strUser==0)
{
alert("Please select a user");
}
}
----- HTML CODE 

<select id="dropdownlistone">
<option value="0">Select</option>
<option value="1">test1</option>
<option value="2">test2</option>
<option value="3">test3</option>
</select>  
<input type="button" onClick="Validate()" value="select"/>
```

Comment: Use a common class, then `getElementsByClassName`. Keep it [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: `Can i pass multiple ids inside a document.getelementbyID` No Use separate call for each of these

Comment: call means for each a function.

Comment: Call means using document.getElementById() separtely for each select box, because you can't pass multiple ids same time

Comment: Just some advice, not really the answer but instead of an input, why not just use the `onChange` event handler to call the function instead of an extra button. So like this: `<select id="dropdownlistone" onChange ="Validate()">`. Also i dont think function names can start with capitals.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case when you need to use classes. Then use `querySelectorAll` method:

```
function Validate() {
    var e = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdownlistone");
    for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        var strUser = e[i].options[e[i].selectedIndex].value;
        var strUser1 = e[i].options[e[i].selectedIndex].text;
        if (strUser == 0) {
            alert("Please select a user");
            return;
        }   
    }
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwNaH/

And here is one more example with more user friendly validation messages: http://jsfiddle.net/cwNaH/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM Method `getElementsByTagName` for `select` box and set an `data-attr to "validate"` for those whom you want to validate, if you dont want it to be validate simply don't add the above mentioned attribute.

Ex. **HTML**

```
<select id="sel1" data-attr="validate">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select> 

<select id="sel2" data-attr="validate">
  <option value="0">Select</option>
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function validate()
{
  var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
  for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++)
  {
     if(ele.getAttribute("data-attr") && ele.getAttribute("data-attr")=='validate')
     {
          // you have all 47 select boxes whoose data-attr is validate
          // each select box will be in ele[i]
          var value= ele[i].options[ele[i].selectedIndex].value;
          var text= ele[i].options[ele[i].selectedIndex].text;

          alert( value+ " : " + text);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry i m new to DOM Method what should i use instead of these...           // you have all 47 select boxes whoose data-attr is validate
          // each select box will be in ele[i]

Comment: @DinaLizooo Just like you are doing document.getElementById for single select box. In above answer all the select box are their in `ele` varibale, just you have to iterate through and validate it. i have updated my answer